# Locks for SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql, locking

Consider a scenario when I have two application A in Java and B in .Net which user a database of SQL server? Both A and B is trying to update a table Product which has ID and Name two columns at the same time. What will happen and how can we avoid such situation.

Please note that product table has large amount of data and A cannot wait for B to complete its task then start and the wait time will be very much and in such case B can throw a timeout error.

Please suggest.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but too broad as it stands. Please do some investigation/coding/experimenting and try to formulate a more specific question if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you will want to synchronize this 
kind of access in your application code.

I've had many situations like this and letting the DB 
handle such race scenarios/conditions is not a good option.

In your case, you may create a third app C which stands in
between A and B (on one side) and the DB (on the other side).
Then in C you can build fine-grained control of your access
to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

By timeouts you mean a deadlock where SQL Server ill kill the "weaker" job (throw a error and roll back the transaction).

The solution depends on your scenario. If you can live with dirty reads and other anomalies you can just  adjust to a less restrictive isolation level (but that it is a unlikely scenario).

peter sugestion is a good one, but if you are unable to create a common entry point at app level you still can do it at RDBMS or DB level by using replication, message broker, creating stag tables, etc.

I suggest anyone else with a similar problem to hit the books since its a very broad topic and you must narrow it to find a solutions best fit your needs.